# How to replace regex matches in values from dict A with values from dict B?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I'm working with JSON files translated into multiple languages. In those JSON files, there is a 'translations' nest that contains placeholders for variables in the following format: {{dv0}} (starts at 0 and grows to whatever number is needed).
I have turned this nest into dictionary A for which the key, value pairs look as follows:

```
'Text 15': 'Hello {{dv0}}.'
'Text 24' 'You are using {{dv1}}.'
'Text 38': 'Your city is {{dv2}}'
```

There is another nest for mapping the placeholders with the actual variables, which I've turned into dictionary B for which the key, value pairs look as follows:

```
'dv0': 'user_name'
'dv1': 'app_name'
'dv2': 'city_name'
```

What I need to do is replace the 'dvx' placeholders in the values from dictionary A with the corresponding values from dictionary B.

I thought using regex would be a good way to do this since I don't know how many variables there will be in each JSON file.

I tried to use the 're' library but I can't seem to find the right logic to accomplish the desired result.

How would you tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
d1={'Text 15': 'Hello {{dv0}}.',
    'Text 24': 'You are using {{dv1}}.',
    'Text 38': 'Your city is {{dv2}}'}

dv2={'dv0': 'user_name',
    'dv1': 'app_name',
    'dv2': 'city_name'}
```

You can do:

```
import re 

for k,v in d1.items():
    if m:=re.search(r'\{\{([^}]+)\}\}', v):
        x=dv2[m.group(1)]
        d1[k]=re.sub(r'\{\{([^}]+)\}\}', x, v)

>>> d1
{'Text 15': 'Hello user_name.', 'Text 24': 'You are using app_name.', 'Text 38': 'Your city is city_name'}
```